# Where clause T-SQL gives not the expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I have the following value in field table_a.value 'abcdefg 10 / 20 / 30 sdafadsfas'.

When I select table_a and apply the following where clause:

```
Where table_a.value like '%[0-9] / 20 / [0-9]%'
```

It will return the value:

'abcdefg 10 / 20 / 30 sdafadsfas'

When I apply the following where clause:

```
Where table_a.value like '%[0-9] / [0-9] / [0-9]%'
```

It will return no values.

Could somebody please explain what is going wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you _trying_ to match?  Can you add more sample data, with both positive and negative cases?

Comment: you can use https://regex101.com/ to test your regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[0-9]` stands for exactly 1 numeric digit.

The pattern `'%[0-9] / [0-9] / [0-9]%'` that you have in your code will be matched if the value of the column contains exactly 1 numeric digit in between spaces, in between slashes.

The value `'abcdefg 10 / 20 / 30 sdafadsfas'` contains 2 numeric digits in that position and not just 1.

For your code to work you should use this pattern:

```
'%[0-9] / [0-9][0-9] / [0-9]%'
```

Comment: I don't understand, according to your explanation it should be: 
'%[0-9][0-9] / [0-9][0-9] / [0-9][0-9]%' , since 10 & 30 also have 2 numberic digits right?
If I just apply [0-9] it will also filter out numbers like 3000.

Comment: @Zayfaya83 For the numbers 10 and 30 there is no problem because you use also the wildcard % so %[0-9] matches 10 (% matches 'abcdefg 1' and [0-9] matches 0) and [0-9]% matches 30 ([0-9] matches 3 and % matches 0)

Comment: Okay, but my dataset also contains example like 5504 / 10 / 124,6. What would be the best way to get always the numbers within 'number / number / number'

Comment: It seems you have goal posts you haven't told us about, @Zayfaya83 . I suggest asking a new question about your real problem, as this answers the question you did ask.

Comment: @Zayfaya83 my answer is about the reason why the pattern `'%[0-9] / [0-9] / [0-9]%'` does not match the value `'abcdefg 10 / 20 / 30 sdafadsfas'`, which is your question. I don't know anything about your actual data. If your requirement is different you can post a new question.